# MediaWiki redirecting the main domain to incorrect page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mediawiki

I am new to wikimedia and recently created a wiki media installation at  /var/www/root folder.

when I click on my main domain ex: http://10.10.0.100, it redirects me to
http//10.10.0.100/index.php/Main_Page and this display an error that page has been deleted.

But when I manually change the URL in the browser to http//10.10.0.100/index.php/Main_page (that is change the letter **p** in the "Main_Page" to lower case ) the right page gets displayed.

But how do to I make my domain to redirect to http//10.10.0.100/index.php/Main_**p**age("page" with lower case **p**) instead of redirecting to http//10.10.0.100/index.php/Main_**P**age

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/Main_Page$ /$1/Main_page [R,L]
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to mediawiki . Can you help me with the file name and the path of the file where this change needs be done.

Comment: this rule for .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

On your wiki, go to the page called `MediaWiki:Mainpage` and edit it to say `Main page`. MediaWiki should then automatically redirect you to that page when no page is given in the URL. It will also change some other things, such as the sidebar link to the main page.

Comment: I cannot see an edit option when i go the page http://10.10.0.100/index.php/Main_page

Comment: @DaD In order to edit pages that start with "MediaWiki", you need to be logged in with an Administrator (sysop) account. If you set up the wiki yourself, the account you created during the installation will be the Administrator.

Comment: Thank you @TiiJ7. Currently the log in functionality for my Wiki is not working. I am unable to create new accounts or log into with the existing accounts. Will try to fix that first and try this solution.